# How to resolve environment variable conflicts and pollution?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, 12factor

#### Context:

As my Node.js project grows larger, the need for configuration increases. This project is the first project where I have switched from a 'legacy configuration file' (say, a `config.js` or `config.json`) to a dotenv (`.env`) file to configure the product.

However, the sheer amount of environment variables used raises a question. These environment variables are all related to OS and networking configuration, so it *seems* justified to configure the application with the dotenv technique.

#### Question:

Say there is one environment variable already set; that would mess up the configuration. A practical example of this would be when you upload a project to some of the bigger (cloud) hosts: the `PORT` environment variable of the machine is set, and may therefore override a default value (see example below), or a value that you might expect. For a system administrator, these errors would be hard to debug.

```js
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
```

How does one deal with these pitfalls?

#### Current situation:

I am currently using `[name of product]_[name of variable]` as template for my environment variables. It feels like a hack (remember private members in JS?) and there is most likely a better solution available.

The second option I have in mind is to be very explicit in the `.env` files by settings all variables used in the product. However, reliability seems to be a weak spot here: if someone were to remove one setting, the entire "defense mechanism" is gone and the product is vulnerable to these bugs again.

Comment: What was wrong with storing variables in 'legacy configuration file'?

Comment: @JasonKim It is easier to manage configurations per environment, rather than per configuration file, as these tend to be scattered around. It's also easier to edit these from the outside (external code would not need a json/js parser for example). The main reason to use this setup, however, was to experiment with the twelve-factor app (https://12factor.net/).